# Using Transform Calc rule in jquery

Tags: jquery, css, rotation, transform, calc

Not sure how to explain my what I'm trying to achieve, but would like to know if I can use the calc() rule with transform:rotate() within jquery.

```
var degree;
    $(".Input").keyup(function(){
        degree = $(".Input").val()
    $(".Line").css({ 'transform': 'rotate('calc( -180deg + degree + deg)')'});
```

My end goal is to offset a rotation by -180 every time someone enters a number into an input field.

Comment: If you want to use calc then be careful to ensure that the + sign in the calc has a space before and after it and also that the -180deg and deg are given as strings.

Answer (score 0):

Figure out there was no need to use calc, below is what i needed to do to achieve offsetting rotation. Pretty much do the math before it goes in the rotate .css

```
var degree;
$(".Input").keyup(function(e){
    degree = $(".Input").val() - 180;
$(".Line").css({ 'transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});
```